# Getting decryption error while extracting data from pdf by selenium webdriver

Tags: java, pdf, encryption, selenium-webdriver, pdfbox

I am trying to extract text from some url that has pdf file but i am getting some error like this - INFO: Document is encrypted
May 27, 2015 9:27:50 AM org.apache.pdfbox.filter.FlateFilter decode

```
public void getTextFromPdf(String urlS) throws IOException {
        driver.get(urlS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        URL url = new URL(driver.getCurrentUrl());
        BufferedInputStream fileToParse = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());

        //parse()  --  This will parse the stream and populate the COSDocument object. 
        //COSDocument object --  This is the in-memory representation of the PDF document
        PDFParser parser = new PDFParser(fileToParse);
        parser.parse();

        //getPDDocument() -- This will get the PD document that was parsed. When you are done with this document you must call    close() on it to release resources
        //PDFTextStripper() -- This class will take a pdf document and strip out all of the text and ignore the formatting and           such.
        System.out.println(urlS);
        String output = new PDFTextStripper().getText(parser.getPDDocument());
        System.out.println(output);
        parser.getPDDocument().close();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: Have you added the required BouncyCastle JARs to your class path?

Comment: No, I havent used BouncyCastle Jars to my class path, Actually i am new for pdfBox and selenium webdriver,

Comment: As far as I know PDFBox requires the BouncyCastle security provider for encryption and signing. Cf. [Apache PDFBox dependencies](https://pdfbox.apache.org/1.8/dependencies.html). The exact version required depends on your PDFBox version.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code for the PDFBox work:

```
        PDDocument doc = PDDocument.loadNonSeq(fileToParse, null);
        String output = new PDFTextStripper().getText(doc);
        doc.close();
```

About the dependencies, [read this](https://pdfbox.apache.org/1.8/dependencies.html) or use the pdfbox-app jar file that you can find [here](https://pdfbox.apache.org/download.cgi).

Comment: The same error im getting by using this code, please give some perfect solution

Comment: @AbhaySingh Could it be that the file is encrypted with a non-null password, or that you used load() and not loadNonSeq() ?